# How to use goose migrations with pgx?

Tags: go, pgx

I have a small go web application that is using PostgreSQL.

My database driver is [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx). Now I am at a point where I want to run migrations automatically at applications start. I found [goose](https://github.com/pressly/goose) for that.

However, I am struggling to use `goose` with the `pgx` driver.

When I run my code I will get:

```
Opening DB
2023/08/09 09:39:28 sql: unknown driver "pgx" (forgotten import?)
```

Here is the shortened main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
"context"
"flag"
"fmt"
"log"
"os"

    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
    "github.com/pressly/goose/v3"

)

func main() {

    // DSN is the PostgreSQL Data Source Name, Database Source Name.
    // Often the same as connection string.
    dsn := flag.String("dsn", "postgres://postgres:password@localhost:5555/plazet", "PostgreSQL data source name")
    flag.Parse()
    
    db, err := openDbConnectionPool(*dsn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to connect to database: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    
    // Ping the database to check if the connection is working
    connection, err := db.Acquire(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to acquire connection: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    
    println("Opening DB")
    
    sql, err := goose.OpenDBWithDriver("pgx", *dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }
    
    println("Migrating")
    
    err = goose.Up(sql, "./migrations")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf(err.Error())
    }
    
    defer connection.Release()
    
    defer db.Close()
    
    // Code for router and stuff...

}
```

I checked the OpenDBWithDriver and pgx is an expected value. What am I missing in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver `pgx` is registered by the `github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/stdlib` package ([source code](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/d17440d5c7e24c6e7cfbf5fe2ce66aabf310fadf/stdlib/sql.go#L84-L94)):

```golang
package stdlib

// ...

func init() {
    pgxDriver = &Driver{
        configs: make(map[string]*pgx.ConnConfig),
    }

    // if pgx driver was already registered by different pgx major version then we
    // skip registration under the default name.
    if !contains(sql.Drivers(), "pgx") {
        sql.Register("pgx", pgxDriver)
    }
    sql.Register("pgx/v5", pgxDriver)
    // ...
```

Try importing that package instead:

```golang
import (
    _ "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/stdlib"
    "github.com/pressly/goose/v3"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone out here searching how to use `pgxpool` together with `goose` -
you can now use `OpenDBFromPool` from the package `pgx/v5/stdlib` to convert a `*pgxpool.Pool` to `*sql.DB`. The function was introduced in version v5.5.0.

```golang
import (
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgxpool"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/stdlib"
    "github.com/pressly/goose/v3"
)

// ...

func main() {
    var pool *pgxpool.Pool
    // setup pool

    goose.SetBaseFS(embedMigrations)

    if err := goose.SetDialect("postgres"); err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }

    db := stdlib.OpenDBFromPool(pool)
    if err := goose.Up(db, "migrations"); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := db.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // run app
}
```